# Chrome extension native messaging got error:"Specified native messaging host not found."

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

My platform OS is win 7.
I started to write extension and try to communicate with C++ app.
Here is manifest of my app: (xxx is my extension id)

```
{
  "name": "com.google.chrome.testc",
  "path": "D:\\testC\\debug\\testC.exe",
  "description": "My Application",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
  "chrome-extension://xxx/"
  ]
}
```

And I also add registry key at: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts: "com.google.chrome.testc: D:\testC\debug\manifest.json"

But when extension called "chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('com.google.chrome.testc', ...)", it always report "Specified native messaging host not found.".

What step I missed? or something wrong above?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The registry key should be `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.my_company.my_application`, and it's `(Default)` value should be `D:\testC\debug\manifest.json`.

From your description it seems that you are instead adding a string value with name `com.my_company.my_application` under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts`